# Export Jquery Fullcalendar events to google calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to export jquery fulcalendar events to google calendar in ical format. as there is option on google calendar to add events from url which has ical format.
Anyone how to do it?

Comment: you'd have to write some code to export the data in the preferred format. There's no built-in feature. Probably easier and better to take the data from its original source (e.g. perhaps it comes from your server database??) than exporting from the fullCalendar front-end. Unless you are talking about sending individual events to google ad-hoc immediately after the user adds them to fullCalendar? For that you could potentially use the Google Calendar API rather than manual iCal imports.

Comment: Alternatively...you mention "google calendar to add events from url " ...you mean adding an iCal feed URL like this https://help.sportlyzer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207593579-Add-iCal-to-Google-Calendar ? i.e. where google checks periodically and imports all events it can find listed at that URL when it visits? For that you could, again, write some server-side code which gets the events from your database and converts them to iCal format (instead of, say, the JSON format you'd convert them to in order to give them to fullCalendar), and returns that iCal-formatted data to the requestor on-demand.

Comment: Either way, I can't see how doing any of this via fullCalendar itself (which is, after all just a bit of user-interface code, not a data store) would be either useful or even possible. Perhaps I have misunderstood, and maybe you can clarify - after all, your question was extremely brief and contained very minimal detail about your situation. If so, then please update with any corrections to my ideas.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you so much. i got your point, you were very help full. I tried your suggested method and it works.. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this with just FullCalendar. Here is an article that explains how to integrate with Google Calendar from a back-end perspective. It served as my reference to making my own FullCalendar + Google Calendar app. 
https://www.sitepoint.com/calendar-as-a-service-in-php-easy-with-google-calendar-api/